# Proper way to power/use a vacuum cylinder?

Tags: vacuum, pneumatic, vacuum-pumps

I'm considering using a vacuum cylinder in my project (like [these ones](http://www.fipa.com/en_GB/products/211441-lifting-cylinders-vacuum-operated)) to lift sheets of cardboard, but being new to mechanical engineering I'm not at all sure what I need to attach to operate one, and the supplier's site definitely offers no details. I think I'll need a vacuum pump, but I don't know what size is necessary (for example, will something like [this mini pump](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/Micro-Vacuum-Air-Pump-Mini-Air-Pressure-Pump-Medical-Pump-30KPa-0-28L-CA-/142183067500?hash=item211ac56f6c:g:wGYAAOSwXeJYLm1L) do?), and whether I just hook up the pump to the hole on the cylinder, or there are other parts that are required.

(I hope this is the right SE site for this; it was a toss-up between this one and the Robotics one.)